# Is there a recommended pattern for building Flatbuffers that have nested types?

Tags: rust, flatbuffers

I have a [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) schema with many nested tables. In the `Typescript` flatbuffers I was able to have each table expose a `to_offset` function that returned the `WIPOffset` for the table on creation time. Then I could assign the result to the nested field in a higher level type, and it worked very well.

In the Rust flatbuffers I cannot make this work as it requires more than one mutable borrow, which of course is not allowed.

Is there any way you recommend working with nested schemas like this where various tables are used throughout the schema in higher level types?

Here is a rough example of what I would like to do:

```
table A {
  f1: string;
}
    
table B {
  fa: A;
  f2: uint;
}

table C {
  fa: A;
  f3: ushort;
}
```

```
fn build_a_offset<'a>(fbb: &'a mut FlatBufferBuilder) -> WIPOffset<A<'a>> {
  let args = AArgs {...
  };

  let a = A::create(fbb, &args);

  a
}

fn build_b_buf() -> Vec<u8> {
  let mut fbb = FlatBufferBuilder::new_with_capacity(1024);
  
  let a_offset = build_a_offset(&mut fbb);

  let b_args = BArgs {
    a: a_offset,
    f2: 30u32,
  }

  let b = B::create(&mut fbb, f_args);

  fbb.finish(b); 

  fbb.finished_data().to_vec()

}
```

Any suggestions on how to structure this properly will be very helpful.

Comment: I believe the answer is that this is not possible, a FlatBufferBuilder instance can only be borrowed mutably one time. I also checked the Rust Flatbuffers integration tests, they work the same way (one instance with one borrow, unless it's a loop then they use reset but still with only 1 borrow). If I am missing something please let me know, otherwise I will work around this.

Comment: Of course the FlatBuffers API allows this, there examples and tests included that do it. Did you read https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html (select "Rust") ?

Comment: I did read those examples, but they are not exactly what I needed to do.
I found the solution, it was just using lifetimes in the right way. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did find an answer, I was not using lifetimes correctly.

```
fn build_a_offset<'a>(fbb: &'mut FlatBufferBuilder<'fbb>) -> WIPOffset<A<'a>> {
  let args = AArgs {...
  };

  let a = A::create(fbb, &args);

  a
}

fn build_b_buf() -> Vec<u8> {
  let mut fbb = FlatBufferBuilder::new_with_capacity(1024);
  
  let a_offset = build_a_offset(&mut fbb);

  let b_args = BArgs {
    a: a_offset,
    f2: 30u32,
  }

  let b = B::create(&mut fbb, f_args);

  fbb.finish(b); 

  fbb.finished_data().to_vec()

}
```

I needed to change the signature for the `fbb` ref to this:

```
fbb: &'mut FlatBufferBuilder<'fbb>
```

It was appending the suffix lifetime instead of the lifetime prepending the reference. This is because a prepended lifetime controls the life of the *reference*, and what is required is to control the life of the *data* included in the reference (that is what an appended `<'fbb>` does in Rust).

It would be good to add more examples to the tutorial for things like this. I could help at some point if that is something you need.